# Make a geological map from a shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have geological data in shapefile, I do not know which data to open and how, from attribute table in QGIS. I need just a map but I do not have an experiences with GIS.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: What type of geological map are you trying to create? what are the names / data types of the attributes?

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you are looking to do / your question. With QGIS to open a map you will load the shapefile (file extension .shp). This will produce the map.  To look at the specific attributes of the map, right click the shapefile within QGIS (on the far right of the screen under the layers panel) and select "Open Attribute Table".

Comment: I think the user wants to know which attributes to use to style their geological map.